# How can I use websocket with the help of pusher to get data from database?

Tags: php, database, websocket, pusher

I'm using websockets with pusher , PHP and some Javascript. I want  display some information from my database to my client. My goal is to refresh the client when an information has insert into my database.
but am facing some problems ..
how can combine between pusher and websocket to get those data ?
how can I get data from database using websockets and a pusher for doing a real time web application that whenever i added data to the database by default they will be shown in my client page ?

Comment: Please add some code or example to your post

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Before posting a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code where you are inserting information into the database, you can also [trigger an event](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#publishing-events) containing that data to Pusher.

It's up to you which channel to send the event on. You could have a channel per table, or a channel per row.

Then in your browser-side JavaScript you can subscribe to any channels you wish to receive updates on. See [here](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#bind-events) for documentation on how to do this.